# How to combine Higher Order Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I cleanly combine Higher Order Components? Currently I have something like this, and there has to be a cleaner way to combine and componse HOC's

```
const appWithWidth = withWidth()(App);

const appWithReduxAndWidth = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(appWithWidth);

const appWithRouterAndCookiesAndReduxAndWidth = withRouter(withCookies(appWithReduxAndWidth));

export default appWithRouterAndCookiesAndReduxAndWidth;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `recompose` is a great library for this.

For example, use [compose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#compose):

```
export default compose(
    withWidth(all_the_cookie_width), 
    withCookies, 
    withMilk, 
    withHoldTheSprinkles
)(App);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `compose` from [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#compose) which combines multiple higher-order components.

```
import { compose } from 'recompose'

export default compose(
  withWidth,
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  withCookies,
  withRouter
)(App)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [compose](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/compose.md) included with redux:

```
import { compose } from 'redux';

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  withCookies
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  withWidth()
)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the compose worked, but the order matters as per my testing. When I used withRouter, withWidth from material-ui, it was showing an error of 'setState in infinite loop'. Not sure about the reason, probably some can explain. Here is my code and will help someone.

```
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
....
...
....
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, null),
    withRouter,
  withWidth()
)(AppNav);
```